#  Should we encourage people to say which variant of Spanish are using?

Tags: discusión

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are we going to deal with spanish regional variations?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-are-we-going-to-deal-with-spanish-regional-variations)

I see that a lot of questions of general or daily use of Spanish can have different answers depending on the region or country and most of these answers can be correct. However, depending on the region, only one answer would apply for the user asking. This is difficult to see because there are a lot of answers claiming to be "the right one" without saying in which region is used that. Thus, my question is the following:

Should we encourage people to say which variant of Spanish are using?