# Under what circumstances should a posted answer be migrated to the comment of another's answer?

Tags: discusión

I'm a little new to the spanish SE, so I'm a bit unfamiliar with the norms of the community.  I posted an answer to [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-to-say-something-is-annoying-in-spanish/2635#2635), which prompted a moderator to suggest migrating my answer to the comment of the accepted answer.  Granted, my answer is a bit shorter than the accepted answer, but my answer is different from previous answers.  What are the justifications to demote it from answer to comment?  Granted: I don't mind changing it to a comment.  I just want to understand the reasoning behind it.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It was me who made that suggestion to you. Briefly, the accepted answer and your answer are both valid, as they are the translations for that word. Thus, it is quite weird to have two valid answers in different places, especially for future readers seeking an answer for this question. In my opinion, it's better to have a great single answer which have all the possible translations and uses instead of having them split in different answers.

There was a discussion about dealing with answers regarding [differences in dialects](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-are-we-going-to-deal-with-spanish-regional-variations), and it seems that is better to make comments about "in X place it is say Y" instead of writing it in a separated answer.

So, my opinion is that different possible translations should be included in accepted/top voted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think it's a judgment call.  I would be happy with it remaining a separate answer, or being merged into the existing one--basically at the OP's choosing (that's you, @Paul!).

It is a distinct answer, and therefore worthy of it's own up (or down) votes, as @TomAu pointed out in his own comment.

It's also short enough, that adding it to the existing answer would also be perfectly acceptable.